# Angular POST to Clojure Ring receivesResponse for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404

Tags: angularjs, clojure, cors, ring

I am working to overcome cors issues with my Angular / Clojure app and I am having trouble unerstanding what syntax to use in order to avoid the Access-Control-Allow-Origin error for POST and GET requests

I have added this code to my clojure controller where my routes are found and it seems to fix the issue for GET requests:

```
(POST "/node/create" request
    (let [node_object (or (get-in request [:params :data])
                          (get-in request [:body :data])
                          "ROUTER_ERROR")]
      {:status 200
       :headers {"Content-Type" "application/json"}
       :body (recursiftion.model/createNode node_object)
      }
))

(defn allow-cross-origin  
  "middleware function to allow crosss origin"  
  [handler]  
  (fn [request]  
   (let [response (handler request)]  
    (assoc-in response [:headers "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"]  
         "*"))))

(def app
 (-> (handler/api app-routes)
      (middleware/wrap-json-body {:keywords? true})
      (middleware/wrap-json-response)
      (allow-cross-origin)))
```

And this Angular code

```
this.post = function (object) { 

    console.log('BANG', object);

    return $http({
                method: "post",
                url: "https://mywebserveraddress.com/node/create",
                data: object
            }); 
    };
```

But I still have related errors for my POST requests:

```
preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404
```

I am looking for the right syntax to add to my clojure application in order for me to make cross domain ajax requests from my angular spa that will live on localhost for development and external servers from my production environment.

I am very grateful for help you can give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS requires non-`GET` requests to send a so-called "preflight" requests, using the `OPTIONS` method. Your code returns 404 because their is no handler for `(OPTIONS "/node/create" ...)`.

A better - but still very much not complete - CORS middleware would be shaped like:

```
(def ^:private cors-headers
  {"access-control-..." ...})

(defn wrap-cors
  [handler]
  (fn [request]
    (some-> (if (= (:request-method request) :options)
              {:status 200}
              (handler request))
            (update :headers merge cors-headers))))
```

But there are more intricacies (like `*` not being a valid value for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in some cases), so I'd recommend to go with an already existing library, e.g. [`ring-cors`](https://github.com/r0man/ring-cors) or [`ring.middleware.cors`](https://github.com/jumblerg/ring.middleware.cors), to take care of them.

Comment: thanks . can you please post the syntax needed for the (defn wrap-cors function when using ring-cors or ring.middleware.cors ? i In addition to the cors features for GET and POST, I also need it to return json

Comment: Instead of your `allow-cross-origin`, you'd use `wrap-cors` with the respective parameters. Both projects' READMEs have short examples on that. :)

Comment: this worked for me:

(def app 
  (-> (handler/api app-routes)
      (middleware/wrap-json-body {:keywords? true})
      (middleware/wrap-json-response)
      (wrap-cors routes #"^http://localhost:9000$")))